# error term for double integral approximation by midpoint rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I found following statement in the book that I'm reading: Using Taylor series expansions it is easy to prove that:
$$
\left|h^2\cdot f(x_0,y_0)-\iint\limits_{D}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\right|\le\frac{h^4}{24}\cdot\left(\max_{(x,y)\in D}\left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right|+\max_{(x,y)\in D}\left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right|\right)
$$
where $D=[x_0-\frac{h}{2},x_0+\frac{h}{2}]\times[y_0-\frac{h}{2},y_0+\frac{h}{2}]$. Any hint on how to actually prove this?

Comment: Depends on the assumptions on $f$. Do you assume continuous derivatives of second order?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that derivatives of $f$ are continuous up to any order.

Comment: The first-order Taylor approximation will do the job. You can apply it to $\int f(x,y^*)\,dx$ with a fixed $y^*$. This gives an estimate for the integral involving $f(x_0,y^*) $ and $f_{xx}$. Then estimate the integral $\int f(x_0,y)\,dy$. Essentially, you are just using the 1D midpoint rule twice.

Comment: I am confused by this result.
Aren't there any contributions from the crossed gradient $\mathrm{max} \big| \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \big|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment for completeness:

The first-order Taylor approximation will do the job. You can apply it to $\int f(x,y^*)\,dx$ with a fixed $y^*$. This gives an estimate for the integral involving $f(x_0,y^*) $ and $\sup |f_{xx}|$. Then estimate the integral $\int f(x_0,y)\,dy$ in terms of $f(x_0,y_0)$ and $\sup |f_{yy}|$. Essentially, you are just using the 1D midpoint rule twice.